# Why the size of a Delphi record is not increased when a procedure is included?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have two records with the same fields and one of them has a set of procedures. Why the Size of both records is the same?

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

type
  TData = record
    Age : Byte;
    Id  : Integer;
  end;

  TData2 = record
    Age : Byte;
    Id  : Integer;
    procedure foo1;
    procedure foo2;
    procedure foo3;
  end;

procedure TData2.foo1;
begin

end;

procedure TData2.foo2;
begin

end;

procedure TData2.foo3;
begin

end;

begin
  try
    Writeln('SizeOf(TData) = '+ IntToStr(SizeOf(TData)));
    Writeln('SizeOf(TData2) = '+ IntToStr(SizeOf(TData2)));
    Readln;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;

end.
```

Comment: Adding methods never increase instance size, it applies both to record instances and objects.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - no, it does not. It increases only class metadata, instance size does not change. The only way to increase instance size other than by fields is by interfaces.

Comment: @Serg You are right, I am wrong. Sorry. I thought that each instance had a copy of the VMT. I assumed that because of the virtual method interceptor. But that works by creating a copy of the VMT. Obviously I need to check my facts before opening my mouth.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - yes, other from fields an instance contains pointers to vtables - class VMT and vtables for interfaces. Also since Delphi 2009 there is one hidden field to implement monitor locks.

Comment: 'Also since Delphi 2009 there is one hidden field to implement monitor locks' - again, someone shoot the ex-java developer at Embarcadero.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because the record itself only carries with the data that composes the record and no procedures or functions. The procedures and functions are a kind of **syntactic sugar** to avoid passing the record itself as a parameter: the *self* variable that is *automagically* added by the compiler for you.

Each method you declare in a record have another parameter for the record itself, for example:

```
  TData2 = record
    Age : Byte;
    Id  : Integer;
    procedure Foo1;
    procedure Foo2(SomeParam: Integer);
  end;
```

is changed to something equivalent to:

```
  PData2 = ^TData2;

  TData2 = record
    Age : Byte;
    Id  : Integer;
  end;

  procedure TData2_Foo1(Self: PData2);
  procedure TData2_Foo2(Self: PData2; SomeParam: Integer);
```

end each call you make is also changed, for example:

```
var
  Data: TData2;
begin
  Data.Foo1;
  Data.Foo2(1);
end;
```

is changed for something equivalent to:

```
var
  Data: TData2;
begin
  TData2_Foo1(@Data);
  TData2_Foo1(@Data, 1);
end;
```

I have no Delphi at hand to check if the parameter is added at the beginning or at the end of your parameter list, but I hope you get the idea.

Of course there's no real syntax for this, since it is done *on the fly* by the compiler and thus, for example, the procedure names are not changed. I did that in a try to make my answer easy to understand.

Comment: About memory structure at function/method calls, see http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Program_Control which clearly states "Methods use the same calling conventions as ordinary procedures and functions, except that every method has an additional implicit parameter Self, which is a reference to the instance or class in which the method is called. The Self parameter is passed as a 32-bit pointer.
Under the register convention, Self behaves as if it were declared before all other parameters. It is therefore always passed in the EAX register"

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez: I presume that with a 64 bit target, the Self pointer passed to the method would be a 64 bit pointer.

Comment: Is this the same for Classes, I assume?

Comment: @Leonardo Not exactly. Methods from classes get the extra-parameter, but a virtual method call is not resolved at compile time, but at runtime using the VMT. Records doesn't have a VMT and doesn't support virtual methods or even inheritance.

Comment: @jachguate - at runtime? That I wouldn't have imagined (now that I think about it it kind of makes sense, a collection of mixed objects for example.)

Comment: It makes sense. That's the way polymorphism works! 

At compile time, a piece of code invoking a virtual method doesn't know really which instances may come during runtime, so the program have to wait until that piece of code is executed to find the right method to execute depending on the type of object for the instance on wich the call is made. Each class have a Virtual Method Table (VMT) that holds the address for all the virtual methods of that class and the program looks up this table to find the address to invoke.

Answer (score 0):

Procedures do not take space. Compiler will hook them up properly. Their addresses do not need to be in memory at runtime for each record. If you look at the representation of TData2 in memory you will not find the procedures.

Comment: This is somewhat imprecise. Procedures do take memory. The code occupies memory. This answer repeats the facts stated in the question without explaining why. The answer is that the code addresses are static and known at compile time and so do not need to be stored in the record.